# Function to create dichotomic var (0/1) using mutate and case_when

Tags: r, function, dplyr, case-when

I'm trying to create a function that will recode variables with categories 1 / 2 into 0 / 1.
Something like this:

```
var_dic <- function(data, x){
  mutate(x_rec, case_when(
              x == 1 ~ 1,
              x == 2 ~ 0,
              TRUE ~ NA_real_))
}

var1 <- c('1', '2', '1', '1', '2', NA, '2', NA)
var2 <- c('1', '1', '2', '2', '2', NA, '2', NA)
id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6, 7, 8)
testing.df <- data.frame(id, var1, var2)
```

But I'm getting an error related to 'x_rec'. I want that part of the code to establish the name of the new var. I'm guess i should include paste0 somewhere, but not sure how or where in the code.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `data` as well

```
var_dic <- function(data, x){
   data %>%
      mutate(!! {{x}} := case_when(
          {{x}} == 1 ~ 1,
          {{x}} == 2 ~ 0,
          TRUE ~ NA_real_))
    }
```